# Using Boruta and Scaling with neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-data, feature-selection, optimal-scaling

When using Boruta for variable selection and also scaling your complete data set to values between 0 and 1 is it typical to select variables using Boruta based on the scaled values or the raw values?

Answer (score 2):

Boruta is based on random forest, which is an ensemble of decision trees. Decision trees do not need to be scaled, because selecting a split on one scale is equivalent to selecting a re-scaled split on an alternative scale.

See also:

[Scaling/Normalization not need for tree based models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262895/scaling-normalization-not-need-for-tree-based-models)