# Normalize row or column while each row is an observation

Tags: normalization, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix compose of row as each observation, column as each property and I want to calculate the distance between each observation.

In this case I think I should normalize each column, instead of row, to a unit vector? I think that would make more sense since each column can have different unit. In contrast if I normalize it by rows to unit vectors, it will be dominated by the property that has larger average value.

Comment: what do you mean by 'distance'?

Answer (score 3):

I think he is asking about feature normalization.

A good discussion already on stats.se:
[How and why do normalization and feature scaling work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41704/how-and-why-do-normalization-and-feature-scaling-work)

Also look at Prof. Ng.'s online course: [week 2](https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/21)

In case you read Chinese, (I guessed from your username, apologies if you do not.)

read about [a good blog post that have some study notes on that part of Prof. Ng.'s lecture.](http://blog.csdn.net/yangliuy/article/details/18455525)