# Why did K means clustering do a poor job in R

Tags: r, k-means

I am trying to implement K means clustering in R, 
Here is what my data look like:

```
 Seq                RegionNames(Zip) X%year(PercentChange)
4002                   53147      -1.683282e-02
4003                   28504      -1.807185e-02
4004                   10591      -5.432917e-03
4005                   96761       1.151578e-02
4006                   32750       5.905045e-03
4007                   54904      -1.193602e-04
4008                   97140       2.667454e-02
4009                   33774       1.932240e-02
4010                   43616      -1.159712e-03
4011                   89011       3.021237e-02
```

I am trying to cluster zip codes (`RegionNames`) based on percentage change in 5 years(`X5Year`)

Here is my code

```
    newallHomesZip <- data.frame(allHomesZip$RegionName,allHomesZip$X5Year) #Making new data frame with only zip and 5 yearly percentage increase
    (cl <- kmeans(na.omit(newallHomesZip), 2))  #omiting Null values and trying to form two clusters
    plot(x, col = cl$cluster) #plotting
```

here is the plot I get :

[image]

Clearly the clusters are not good.

I don't really understand the Kmean method, I want to form clusters based on percent change as magnitude and zip code as identifier

Comment: Post some 10..20 lines of your input data. Link-only derrogations are not considered a good practice on StackOverflow, as the referred content may become un-retrievable in some future time. Thanks for your kinde re-consideration and post update.

Comment: Also in your plot statement you're plotting 'x' which isn't defined in your problem at all.  It wasn't even used when making clusters so if it's unrelated to the clusters you made then I'm not surprised the clusters aren't doing great

Comment: This question really isn't about programming; it's about understanding a particular statistical method. As such, it's probably a better fit for [stats.se] (that fact that you are using R is really irrelevant).

Comment: The "RegionName" variable got input as a factor because it was quoted. (I looked at the original data whereas user3666197 _should_ have told you to post the output of dput so this could be seen, rather than posting screen output.)

Comment: Yes,it was poorly done by me, 

I tried to make some changes, also would note  that my next post don't have the same mistakes,

Thanks

Comment: Homespun wisdom is here important: no clustering method works outstandingly well when there aren't distinct clusters to be found. This is a broader principle independent of which method you use and certainly independent of which software you use.

Comment: The use of dollar signs as part of R syntax is just a detail here. Note that dollar signs tend to get read in CV as TeX/LaTeX mark-up for mathematics. I edited a couple out which had distracting side-effects on your text.

Answer (score 5):

[K-means algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aWzGGNrcic) works with continuous dimensions, and the basic idea is that it considers two elements to be "similar" if their values are "near". This means that k-means only make sense when there is a sense of continuity in the dimensions. Similar zip codes are usually near, but those are hardly a continuous dimension, so it may not be the best clustering criteria; geographical coordinates would probably make more sense.

Also, another problem with k-means is scale: [you should scale all the variables to a similar range](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21226), or otherwise one will have much more weight than the other.

Finally, it's not clear what are the axes of your plot. If you are using two given variables for clustering, you should use those in the plot. K-means clusters will only be related in the dimensions that you use in the algorithm; other dimensions may or may not follow the same clusters.

Comment: what the OP did is like clustering people by weight and including as the two variables their weight and name.