# K-means clustering: is data set standardization strongly advised?

Tags: clustering, k-means, standardization

Let a data set like this:

```
       |   Attribute1     Attribute2    Attribute3
--------------------------------------------------
Obs_1  |        1,00           10,00    4500,00
Obs_2  |        1,10           80,00    3200,00
Obs_3  |        0,90          137,00    95000,00
…      |        …              …        …
Obs_100|        1,05          -65,00    17000,00
```

As you can see, attributes have different ranges; furthermore, their summary statistics would likely return very different distributions.

Now let you want to apply clustering via K-means: how can this affect final result? If you imagine a 3D space with data points, coordinates belonging to `Attribute1` are massed over $x$-axis, while those belonging to `Attribute3` are likely to be strewn over $z$-axis because of very different scale.

My guess is that this overweights `Attributes3` when it comes to minimize Euclidean distances to find cluster means: I guess that K-means finds out that about every `Obs_i` falls in the same cluster according `Attribute1`, therefore it finds out that `Attribute3` is the real discriminant that should be chosen to create clusters.

My question: if my guess is correct, does this mean that some form of standardization should be applied before K-means? Standard score seems a good choice.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21222/3277

Comment: It actually answer my question... ok, close this :)