# Is it right to use different feature scaling techniques to different features?

Tags: machine-learning, standardization, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

I read this post about feature scaling: [all-about-feature-scaling](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35)

The two main `feature scaling` techniques are:

`min-max scaler` - which responds well for features with distributions which are **not Gaussian.**

`Standard scaler` - which responds well for features with **Gaussian distributions**.

I read other posts and examples, and it seems that we always use **one** scaling method (min-max or standard) for **all** the features.

I haven't seen example or paper that suggests:

```
1. go over all the features, and for each feature:
1.1 check feature distribution
1.2 if the feature distribution is Gaussian:
1.2.1 use Standard scaler for this feature
1.3 otherwise:
1.3.1 use min-max scaler for this feature
```

1. Why we are not mixing the scaling methods ?
2. What is wrong or disadvantages with my proposal ?

Comment: Why do you want to scale the features? You ought to have some reason ...

Comment: each feature has it's own scale., and from reading at the internet it seems require reprocessing step. am I missing something ?

Comment: It is a misconception that feature scaling is always needed! That depends on specific models used, and modeling goals.   See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201909/when-to-normalize-data-in-regression/202002#202002