# How to overcome over pruning on CART model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

My experience with `R`, `rpart` model is the model seems to be always too simple / over pruning. In many experiments, I am seeing a over simplified tree with only 1 or 2 split, but I know from the domain knowledge the model should be more complicated.

Currently, I am manually experimenting with `cp` and `minsplit` parameter to get a more complicated tree, sometimes sacrifice cross validation performance to get a more "informative" tree.

Would other models like conditional inference trees be better in terms of over pruning? Or other suggestions to get a more complicated model?

PS, I aware of over-fitting risk, but think the model I got from CART is still too simple. And I remember I read from somewhere that the pruning method proposed in CART may have the problem of "over pruning".

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using a random forest?

Comment: @Sycorax Need to extract some knowledge from tree, to present to business. Executives do not like "black box" model ...

Comment: I am not familiar with rpart but the original CART program of Brieman,, Friedman et al.  which is now available from Salford systems may have a parameter that controls the degree of splitting.  I do not know if the program has a default value for the parameter.  The complexity of the tree that you construct depends on your sample size.  So if the sample size is small it may be  difficult  to generate splits that lead to terminal nodes with more than 1 or 2 cases.

Comment: @hxd1011: Your comment suggests that you're interested in feature importance of trees. See this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/how-to-measure-rank-variable-importance-when-using-cart-specifically-using

Comment: @AlexR. thanks for the link. In addition to importance, I still want to have a "reasonable complicated tree" to show, that is why I ask this.

Comment: I thought rpart allows you to first grow the tree and then prune it as a separate function? Although as far as complexity goes, some tree methods use regularization (in addition to pruning) to control for the depth of the tree, which would allow you to retain more or less levels.

Comment: @AlexR. prune use a separate function is exactly I wanted, or customized pruning. But seems it uses 1SE rule and not easy to change. Any other R libraries are better?

Comment: Check out "rpart.control" to customize the default settings: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf